# Error with "vary for traits"

Tags: ios, xcode8

I have a problem trying to use the "vary for traits", I want to place three buttons in my application but I want those buttons to change when the view is in landscape or portrait, the problem is that when applying my "vary for traits" the changes are not saved.

I'm giving these three buttons a style for the vertical view, but I still do not apply the Vary for traits:

[image]

Since my buttons have the style I want for my vertical view, I use the vary for traits to assign the constranit:[image]

When I already assign the constraint, I click on "Done Varying"

[image]

Now when it happened to my horizontal view it looks like this:

[image]

Now in this view I will apply my Vary for traits to be able to accommodate the buttons and give them another design:
[image]

When I finish adding my Vry for Traits I click on Done and my view looks like this:

[image]

But now the problem is that if we return to my vertical view, my design that had already echoed has been modified:

[image]

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong, I do not know why I do not respect my changes for the vertical view and then for my horizontal view.

Comment: Vary for traits on its own doesn't do anything. It merely sets the default conditions for new constraints that you will apply while it is active. From the screenshots, the only constraint variant you have applied is a larger font in compact, compact traits and this seems to be working. If you want the size and/or position of your buttons to change then you need to add trait-based constraints to those properties.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, the text constraint does respect it but I was looking for it and it does not allow me to do something similar to place an image inside a button plus the title

Comment: Only some properties can be varied based on traits in the storyboard; you can identify these by the small "+"next to them in the property inspector that allows you to add a variant. The image cannot be varied in the storyboard. If you wanted to vary the image you would need to do so in code in your view controller's [willTransitionToTraitColllection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621511-willtransitiontotraitcollection) function